# UIScrollView autolayout loop if content frame is less than scrool view frame

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

Trying to put UIViewController view to scrollview for all possible screen sizes.

```
 class ScrollableContentViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    private var contentView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let view = self.view else {
            return
        }

        view.removeFromSuperview()                

        self.view = scrollView
        scrollView.addSubview(view)
        self.contentView = view.superview
        if let contentView = view.superview {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        let wc = view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
        wc.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
        wc.isActive = true

        let hc = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)
        hc.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 700)
        hc.isActive = true
    }    

}
```

And here is my test ViewController in storyboard
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSxvq.png)

**The problem**

if I put hc.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 100), everything works on small phones with scrolling, but on large screens autolayout loop happens
when I do `hc.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)` everything works on large phones (no scrolling) and no scrolling on small screens - that is works as designed.

**The question**
Why `hc.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 100)` causes layout loop? But at the same time working good on small screens.

Tried to debug it, but got no sufficient results

Comment: Hi Anton, when priority set to 100 in small screen size, the hc constraint most likely be ignored due to view height smaller than scrollView height decided by higher priority constraints. That is why it is working on small screen. I noticed that there have few dash lines in your screenshot (which means constrains with priority lower than 1000). If these constraints also have same priority 100, then the auto-layout system may be confused. It would help to figure out the cause of layout loop if you upload your demo project to somewhere like github.

Comment: No, all of them are more than 500. I will upload project a bit later

Comment: No, all of them are more than 500.
https://bitbucket.org/antonsl/temporary/src/master/SlidingContent/